# How can I use multiprocessing to plot data while sampling sensors?

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, multiprocessing, python-3.7

I am trying to use the multiprocessing python library to plot while collecting data and I do not want to interrupt the data collection or slow it down. I am not sure how to store the data and send it to multiprocessing to cleanly plot. Also not sure if I can use matplotlib.

I have tried to create a pipe and also a queue. Also I have tried using a lock and neither have worked well enough for me. I am not trying to use Pool because I am not running a lot of small processes, I am just running a data collection process and then plotting. From what I understand with playing around with the library, you start a Process and that will get the process to start? Once you join the processes, it will wait until something is returned to then move on in the code. I have also tried my normal data collection and then adding on a separate process for plotting, they would both be continuous loops that would stop with a KeyboardInterrupt.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Pipe
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def collectData(sender):
    xVal = np.random.rand() + np.random.randint(0,10)
    yval = 23 + np.random.rand()
    time.sleep(0.001)
    sender.send([xVal,yVal])

def plottingData(receiver,fig,ax):
    connect = receiver.recv()
    print(connect)
    ax.scatter(connect[0],connect[1])
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter([],[])
    plt.show(block=False)

    receiver, sender = Pipe(False)

    for i in range(10):
        print('Start process...')
        duta = Process(target=collectData, args=(sender,))
        plut = Process(target=plottingData, args=(receiver,fig,ax))

        duta.start()
        plut.start()
        print('...done with process')

    duta.join()
    plut.join()
    print('Completed multiprocessing')
```

This is just a simple example I am trying to code to simulate the data collection and plotting by passing data between them. This is a basic layer to try to build upon.

Some things I am trying to do: Loop my plotting like I currently do. It runs continuously and stop with a KeyboardInterrupt. Add on plotting so that I can see the data but I do not want to slow down the data collection.

From what I have understood with the code as of now. The Processes are looking to finish and then move on, making the continuous collection hard. The plotting tells me this too as I have 10 separate figures open and it does not finish until I close the figure windows. I am trying to pass a pandas data frame to then plot and cannot figure out if that will be possible with a pipe or what.

Any help understanding the multiprocessing library will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As for collecting data in a certain process and plotting it in another you could do something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def collectData(communicator):
    while True:

        xval = np.random.rand() + np.random.randint(0,1)
        yval =  np.random.rand()
        communicator.put([xval,yval]) # we use the Queue here to commuicate to the other process. Any process is
        # allowed to put data into or extract data from. So the data collection process simply keeps putting data in.
        time.sleep(1) # not to overload this example ;)

def update(frame, communicator: Queue): # here frame needs to be accepted by the function since this is used in FuncAnimations
    data = communicator.get() # this blocks untill it gets some data
    xdata.append(data[0])
    ydata.append(data[1])
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim([0, 1]) # set the limits to the values you expect
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    xdata, ydata = [], []
    ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

    communicator = Queue()
    print('Start process...')
    duta = Process(target=collectData, args=(communicator,))
    duta.start()
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, blit=True, fargs=(communicator,))
    plt.show()
    print('...done with process')
    duta.join()
    print('Completed multiprocessing')
```

So the idea is that the duta process keeps adding data to the Queue and the main initial process that calls FuncAnimation keeps waiting untill it finds anything to plot.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this and get back to you!

Comment: So I am trying to do this plotting and if I do it in the Spyder IDE it gets the first two print statements, however, the plot is unresponsive. Now, I tried it in the anaconda terminal and it only got the first print statement, but the plot initialized with an axes, and nothing happens after that. When I close the figure from the terminal run, I got the second print statement saying that it was done, but never the 'completed' print statement. I'm guessing this is due to sending it into an infinite loop so it will continue past the .join() since that is where it waits to finish.

Comment: Interesting, it runs fine on my system. What is the backend of your matplotlib and which version are you running? If it works correctly it should just show the first print statement "Start process...". Did you copy paste my code since it might be that alternative data is not shown on these axes?

Comment: Matplotlib's backend is Qt5Agg. I realized it does work, after 5 minutes I have a couple points on the figure.

Comment: So it works like you would like to or are there still issues?

Comment: It did work but the scope of this project will be upwards of 10 Hz for data collection, and plotting around 1 Hz. Also with Spyder, I cannot run multiprocessing through there, I need to run it in the terminal. I might look to another solution for this problem for ease of use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marc.
I tested the code, however the Figure is not updated.
Matplotlib Version: 3.5.2
Python 3.10.4

The Figure is simply shown with an empty axis. I am not sure how to fix this, fig.canvas.draw() remains with the same plot..

Comment: Could you set the limits of the axes from 0 to 1 

`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
`ax.set_xlim([0,1])`
`ax.set_ylim([0,1])`

I'm hoping you're not seeing anything due to the axes having extremely smal limits.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks @Marc! 
One other detail I found out, in your code you don't set `plt.show(block=False)`, therefore the show command has to be at the very last step, since the GUI creation actually blocks the main thread I think.

Comment: I tried now the past two days to setup a version with `plt.ion()`, or `plt.show(block=False)` to be working  in a multiprocessing program. But did not manage to do it.. 
So I'm super happy I came across your solution here! 

The only point is that the GUI has to be created in the main thread, when I move it to another subprocess it doesn't work again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continuously receive and plot data you may want to use multithreading and matplotlib's FuncAnimation tools. Set up a thread to receive data and store it in some form of list and then in the animation function update the line/scatter plot values to see the changes reflected on your plot. Make sure that the animation is running in the main loop of your program as otherwise this may cause problems.

Comment: I have looked into this a little and am actually spending the next day or two trying to do it with FuncAnimate. If I am running a collection loop of code that has its own timing to sample, can I put this function inside there or would I have to control it from the animation function since you could set  the interval at which it updates.

Comment: If you wish to obtain samples of data much faster than the animation then you would need to use a thread. The collection thread and the animation function can have different timings, however if your sampling rate is around ~50ms per data point you could maybe avoid using threads altogether and just put the data retrieval inside your funcanimation animate/update function

Comment: I am playing around with FuncAnimation currently. I am reading data serially from an Arduino and then trying to plot it. I have gotten stuck because the code only runs the first time in the function but I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. If I am able to fix this, FuncAnimation should work for this specific application but threading might make this easier.

Comment: @Tomwell17 Did you finally solve the problem? I've got a similar problem, and my problem is FuncAnimation does not return the codeflow to other processes. (my update function cannot run, as Funcanimation blocks the system)